# Axios mock: Received number of calls: 0

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to do a simple mock for my get All method.I'm getting this error:

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0

following is my mock configurations.

```
jest.mock("axios", () => {
  return {
    create: jest.fn(() => ({
      get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: [{ name: "test_role" }] })),
      post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { name: "test_role" } })),
      put: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { name: "updated_role" } })),
      delete: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: "" })),
      interceptors: {
        request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
        response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
      },
    })),
  };
});
```

here is my test:

```
it("get all roles", async () => {
  //Arrange
  const allRoles = [{ name: "test_role" }];

  //Act
  const result = await role.getAll();

  //Assert
  expect(JSON.stringify(result.data)).toBe(JSON.stringify(allRoles));
  expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: `expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` - you expect a mock function you _literally just created_ to have received a call? That's never going to pass. I'd recommend not mocking Axios at all, certainly not manually - use something like Nock or MSW to mock at the transport layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jest.fn()` creates a new mock function and has no reference to other functions that it was used to create. Hence, you will need to explicitly define which mock function you expect to have been called. E.g. if you wanted `post` to be called - you will need to define this as follows:

```
expect(axios.create.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

You can reuse this syntax to expect other method calls.